# SWT - MessageBox opening and closing

Tags: java, swt, jface

Is it possible to open and close a messagedialog without the user having to click buttons?

When the user clicks a button on my form, the action from that button goes server side and gathers a list of items, takes a couple of seconds.  I want a way to tell the users that the action is in progress.  I was thinking a messagedialog with some text. .

Opens the message

```
MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Information", "Getting List From Server");
```

Then some how closes it
(something like `MessageDialog.close`)?

I looked at a progress bar but that was more than I really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might look like a big overhead at first, but I would suggest using an [`IProgressMonitor`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIProgressMonitor.html) which shows the progress of your task.

The user will know whats going on when he/she sees a progress bar, rather than a dialog that looks like the gui is frozen.

[Here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html) is an article by Eclipse on how to use progress monitors correctly.

If you really want to go for your idea (which I would not suggest), you can try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    BazMessageDialog dialog = new BazMessageDialog(shell, "Information", null, "Getting List From Server", MessageDialog.INFORMATION, new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"}, 0);
    dialog.open();

    /* Do your stuff */

    dialog.reallyClose();

    shell.dispose();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

public static class BazMessageDialog extends MessageDialog
{

    public BazMessageDialog(Shell parentShell, String dialogTitle,
            Image dialogTitleImage, String dialogMessage,
            int dialogImageType, String[] dialogButtonLabels,
            int defaultIndex) {
        super(parentShell, dialogTitle, dialogTitleImage, dialogMessage,
                dialogImageType, dialogButtonLabels, defaultIndex);
        setBlockOnOpen(false);
    }

    public void reallyClose()
    {
        cancelPressed();
    }

}
```

This however, will not block your remaining gui, so the user will be able to use it in the meantime.

**EDIT**:

Just found out, that [Opal](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) has something called an [InfiniteProgressPanel](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/InfiniteProgressPanel), which might be something for you. Have a look...

Comment: I have looked at both IProgressMonitor and Opal.  I like Opal.  I downloaded the jar file.  But having problems loading it in my plug-in project in eclipse

Comment: What's the problem you are having? Follow method 1 in [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) link and it will work.

Comment: Let me thank you Baz for the time and effort you put in to helping me learn this stuff.  You can not imagine how much you have help me and I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @jkteater You're welcome. I wish someone had helped me when I was learning SWT :)